# Why do I repeatedly get EADDRINUSE errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, localhost, port

I may know the answer to this question but I am looking for confirmation in case I am missing something.

I am in a development mode on a full stack Node/React project. My server is running on port 5000. My client is running on port 3000. I am proxying my frontend routes to node for the actual IO. All of that seems to be running just fine.

I am working from my home office so when I quit work each evening I simply walk away from my work. Sometime later that night my machine logs me out. That is probably NOT a best practice.

The next working day I sit down to work, I login, I execute npm run dev (I'm running concurrently). Typically the front end comes up No Problem. However (even though the app executes properly) my console displays ERRADDRINUSE :::5000.

It looks like everything is going ok but I suppose something may be lying in wait for me. And, it also indicates that it isn't completely benign.

Here is my thought. I do get automatically logged out each evening but apparently that is not necessarily closing the ports down (at least not port 5000). I am thinking that I should probably be performing and actual shut down or restart every evening.

Am I right? And, when you confirm, would you mind including the "why"? I am still learning as I go. Thanks.

Comment: run `sudo kill -9 \`sudo lsof -t -i:5000\`` to kill the service running on that port, which is the server in this case

Answer (score 0):

ERRADDRINUSE appears when there is already a process listening on port 5000. Check to see if the process is running before you start the node process again.

```
ps -A | grep node
```

If the process needs to be restarted for whatever reason you probably want to kill that process first and then try to start it again.

Comment: I guess what is unclear to me is why, if I am being logged out of my machine at night after a period of time, and I'm sure that is happening because I have to log back in each morning, does PORT 3000 (my client side) seem to get closed down, but PORT 5000 (my server side) does not? Looking forward to the day when I deploy this app, on say heroku, is there something I am going to have to deliberately do to make sure this doesn't happen in production?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR:

Running `ps aux | grep node` will allow you to determine the PID of the process that is listening on listening on port 5000 and you can kill it with `kill -9 PID`.
(where PID is the process id of the hanging process)

---

Little more explanation:

Your two servers are each running as independent *processes* within your system. If you run a command-line program like `top`, you will be able a list of the running processes, including the process identifier or PID.

When the state of your system changes (logging out, shutting down, loses network connection). The operating system issues a *signal* (sometimes referred to as a software interrupt). The process is then responsible for deciding how to proceed after receiving the signal. (There is separate code for this known as signal handlers). Most modern web frameworks already have signal handlers built in to respond to the common signals.

Usually, a process is terminated when the SIGTERM signal is issued or is forced to stop when the SIGKILL signal is issued.

However, it is not uncommon to have a process that hangs every now and then. (I have seen this before with nodejs servers). To stop them, the easiest thing to do would be to issue a SIGTERM (gracefully stop the process) or SIGKILL signal (force stop the process) manually to the process yourself.

The `kill -9 PID` command can be used to issue a SIGKILL signal to the process.

For more on this see the Linux man-pages on processes and/or signals.

Comment: I guess what is unclear to me is why, if I am being logged out of my machine at night after a period of time, and I'm sure that is happening because I have to log back in each morning, does PORT 3000 (my client side) seem to get closed down, but PORT 5000 (my server side) does not? Looking forward to the day when I deploy this app, on say heroku, is there something I am going to have to deliberately do to make sure this doesn't happen in production?